# Blender renders invisible black object in my scene that I cant get rid of

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I have been working on a dystopian city environment for some time and when test rendering, there is a huge black cube in the middle of my scene. I have tried using Alt + H and Shift + H to unhide everything but this does not seem to work as I cannot see the cube in the viewport. I have also tried deleting certain objects and looking through the collections but I still cannot seem to find the cube which is only visible in the render. Please help as I do not know what else to try!

Answer (score 1):

Guys I figured out how to fix this. If you ever have an annoying invisible object in your scene that you cannot find anywhere in the viewport go to the top right filter settings, select 'Hidden' and it will display all of the hidden objects in your scene which you can then delete!